# Accessing custom enum fields

Tags: java, enums

How can I access (without reflection) `RAIN` and `WIND` fields from some other class? My IDE shows errors when I try to reference `Season.FALL.RAIN`, `Season.FALL.WIND`, and call `Season.FALL.getWind()`.
`Season` enum compiles fine:

```
public enum Season {
  WINTER,
  SPRING,
  SUMMER,
  FALL {
    public static final String RAIN = "rain";
    public final String WIND = "wind";

    public String getWIND() {
      return WIND;
    }
  };
}
```

Why is Java allowing these members if I cannot access them from the outside? I cannot access them even inside the `Season` enum. I use Java 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because class of `FALL` constant is a subclass of `Season` class - you can imagine it as you declared it as anonymous class.

You can emulate similar situation without enums too:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class C {
            public int i;
        }
        C c = new C() {
            public int a;
        };
        System.out.println(c.a); // wont compile
    }
```

The `c` instance is still treated as of `C` class (despite the actual class is something like `C$1`) and there is no `a` field in `C` class. Java allows `a` field to serve to members of the subclass, not to anybody from outside. The subclass exists but is not accessible literally. Reflection access is possible. The same holds for your enum example.

Comment: I have to add small note afterwards: there is difference between my example and enum `Season` example. The `Season.FALL.getClass()` is class baked behind the scene whereas the `C$1` is explicitly defined anonymous class. I can change the declaration `C c` to `var c` in my example and code becomes compilable (see https://nipafx.dev/java-var-anonymous-classes-tricks for best explanation of this trick). I can't think up how to apply this trick to capture class of `FALL` enum constant.

Answer (score 1):

For defining also the internal attributes as enum, this will work:

```
    enum Season {
        UNDEFINED,
        WINTER(Phenomenon.RAIN),
        SPRING(Phenomenon.WIND),
        SUMMER(Phenomenon.HOT),
        FALL(Phenomenon.RAIN, Phenomenon.WIND);

        enum Phenomenon {
            RAIN,
            WIND,
            HOT
        };

        Phenomenon[] phenomena;

        Season(Phenomenon... phenomena) {
            this.phenomena = phenomena;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name() + ":  " + Arrays.toString(phenomena);
        }
    }
```

Then printing/searching:

```
        for (Season s : Season.values()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();

        Season s = Season.SPRING;
        for (Phenomenon p : new Phenomenon[] { Phenomenon.HOT, Phenomenon.WIND }) {
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(s.phenomena, p) >= 0) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Phenomenon [%s] happens in season [%s]", p, s.name()));
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format("Phenomenon [%s] does not happen in season [%s]", p, s.name()));
            }
        }
```

will print:

```
UNDEFINED:  []
WINTER:  [RAIN]
SPRING:  [WIND]
SUMMER:  [HOT]
FALL:  [RAIN, WIND]

Phenomenon [HOT] does not happen in season [SPRING]
Phenomenon [WIND] happens in season [SPRING]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but you can have it like this:

```
public enum Season {
  WINTER,
  SPRING,
  SUMMER,
  FALL;
  public static final String RAIN = "rain";
  public static final String WIND = "wind";
}
```

If you want those two fields to only be accessible in `FALL`, that's not possible. Each enum value is of the same final class, and if you have a static field in a class, it's available regardless of which value of the class you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Season declaration does not accept these methods and properties.

Try to build a more detailed enum, like this:

```
public enum Season {
  WINTER,
  SPRING,
  SUMMER,
  FALL("rain", "wind");
  
  
  private String rain;
  private String wind;
  
  
  private Season () {}
  
  private Season(String rain, String wind) {
      this.rain = rain;
      this.wind = wind;
  }
  
  public String getRain() { return this.rain; }
  public String getWind() { return this.wind; }
}
```

So you can access to these properties like this:

```
System.out.println(Season.FALL.getRain());
```